# Installing Ubuntu 64-bit on Windows 7 64

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 64 on a Windows 7 64-bit host running an AMD64 processor. I've pointed it to a VirtualClone Drive of the ISO image (which mapped it as the I: drive), but it starts up with just the cursor and nothing else and just sits there. I've also tried pointing the Storage to the ISO image, but it throws this error:

```
Result Code:
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:
Medium
Interface:
IMedium {1d578f43-5ef1-4415-b556-7592d3ccdc8f}
Callee:
IVirtualBox {3f36e024-7fed-4f20-a02c-9158a82b44e6}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the ISO works when written to disk. I strongly suspect you have a damaged ISO.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox ?

Comment: Echoing Sathya.  AFAIK, 64-bit compatibility was only added relatively recently.

Comment: Found out the problem: For some reason, Firefox couldn't download the ISO file correctly -- it fetched a portion of the file and died. Downloaded with another browser w/out any issues and it worked beautifully :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer as provided by OP in comments:

The ISO file was downloaded incorrectly. After re-downloading, it worked fine.

Remember to check your checksums when downloading large, important things like OS ISOs!